# creating react forms background image

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I want to build a form with a background image but I have not been able to do that. Can anyone help me understand

I was expecting to have a picture behind the form being shown

Comment: Welcome to SO, Gideon! Could you add your code so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.